# How to add a NSTextField to the subview of another NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, appkit

I have seen an app on OSX that show as below:
[image]

And i can see the control structure by the UIElementInspect tool.

[image]

From the screenshot, we can see that there is a big NSTextField, and it has so many small sub NSTextField, each sub NSTextField can be clicked, edit and remove by mouse or key event.
I want to implement the same function, but i can not put a NSTextField to the subview of another NSTextField. Who can tell me how to implement the similar function.

Comment: Take a look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006555

Comment: @Astoria  Thank you very much, it helps me